# Testing responses in node.js?

Tags: unit-testing, node.js, mocha.js

I have just downloaded `mocha.js` and have ran some basic tests with `expect.js` to ensure that it's working properly.

But what about testing responses in my `node` application at a specific url? I.e how do I test what response I get from navigating to `/users` for instance?

Using Expresso, mocha.js's predecessor, I could do `assert.response(server, req, res|fn[, msg|fn])` and test the response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one thing that I love about Node.js/Javascript, doing this sort of thing is simple once you got the hang of it.

In short, you run your server code and then actually use either [Request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) or Superagent to make these HTTP requests. I personally prefer [Superagent](http://visionmedia.github.com/superagent/) because of it's automatic JSON encoding, but be careful, the docs are out of date and incorrect, YMMV. Most people choose Request.

Simple Mocha Example using Request:

```
describe('My Server', function(){
    describe('GET /users', function(){
        it("should respond with a list of users", function(done){
            request('http://mytesturl.com/users', function(err,resp,body){
                assert(!err);
                myuserlist = JSON.parse(body);
                assert(myuserlist.length, 12); 
                done(); 
            }); 
        }); 
    });
});
```

Hopefully that helps. Here is a sample of my Mocha (CoffeeScript) testing using this style with complete detailed examples: https://github.com/jprichardson/logmeup-server/blob/develop/test/integration/app.test.coffee Oh ya, it also is using Superagent.